# Excel Date to String conversion excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a date in Excel which is a date, and the format of it is as `2012/04/19`.

I want to replace the `/` sign with `-` so it will have the format `2012-04-19`. I want to replace it when I insert to MySQL, using PHP. What is the query?

Comment: Excel and mysql have not a lot to do with eachother. Please add some code and a better explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: How are you planning to bring this data into MySQL?  This is a critical omitted piece of information here.

Comment: You can use str_replace if you are using php script to read excel and then insert in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts.

What this means to you is that an Excel date whose text format is `2012/04/19` can already be inserted as is into a MySQL date column.

Internally, most databases store dates and timestamps in seconds since the epoch.  So with regard to the particular format your date data has in the database, you only need to worry about that at the time you query.  If you want to query out your dates in the format `2012-04-19`, you could use `DATE_FORMAT()`, e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(your_date_col, '%Y-%m-%d')
FROM yourTable;
```

Actually, MySQL might give `2012-04-19` as the default date format in output, but `DATE_FORMAT` covers you should this not be the case.